# AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'merge'

Tags: pandas, numpy, merge, attributeerror, pandas-styles

I have a problem like that, when i styled data (conditional format) with pandas, i can't merge that datas. You can find my code and error below,
Can anyone give me an advice?

CODE:

```
cm = sns.diverging_palette(10, 140, s=99, l=50,
                              n=9, center="light", as_cmap=True)

df_style1 = df_b.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
df_style2 = df_c.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
df_last = df_style1.merge(df_style2, on= 'EKSPER_ADI', how='left')
```

ERROR:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-148-d1b2ae3dc7a6> in <module>
  4 df_style1 = df_b.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
  5 df_style2 = df_c.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
  ----> 6 df_last = df_style1.merge(df_style1, on= 'EKSPER_ADI', how='left')

 AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'merge'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not possible, first use `merge` and then apply `style`s:

```
df = df_b.merge(df_c, on= 'EKSPER_ADI', how='left')
df_style2 = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
```

Comment: please be more elaborate